# configuration mistake on direct zone in bind9 on ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, bind, internal-dns, configuration-management

I am trying to configure a server with bind9 on `ubuntu 16.4.2 LTS`. I configured the DNS direct zone like this:

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     asirrafaas.edu. server.asirrafaas.edu. (
                              2         ; Serial
                        3024000         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      asirrafaas.edu.
@       IN      A       10.0.0.15
@       IN      AAAA    ::1
```

When I execute `named-checkconf db.asirrafaas.edu` the system gives me the following error:

> db.asirrafaas.edu:1: syntax error near ';'
>   When I use service bind9 status, it says tghat all is ok
>   My server has ip address 10.0.0.15/8

Comment: Why are you trying to point a `CNAME` to an IP address? That's not what a `CNAME` is for.

Comment: I fixed it, but still wrong

Comment: I followed that guy, (minute 8) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SC6crXYwFaA

Comment: Why are you using `named-checkconf` on a zone file, as opposed to `named-checkzone` for zone files?